# Preserving historical data in a timeseries container with row expiration

Tags: java, c, nosql, griddb

I am using GridDB's timeseries row expiration to have old rows drop out of a dataset.
But I want the dataset to include some yet older rows, with a special status as historical data which foregoes said expiration.

To be more concrete, I have historical weather data from the 70's and earlier, and I got recent weather data from this year. I want this years data to expire after
some time, so that with new data added on the time frame of this years data is always the same. Lets say 3 months (100 days) long, but the historical data needs to persist.

I tried to first add the historical data, then switch the container settings, and then add this years data. 
I got this error when I tried to switch the expiration timer:

[60084] [60084:DS_TIM_INVALID_SCHEMA_OPTION] elapsed time of expiration is different. old = -1, new = 100 ()

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?